# Is there a way to evaluate a multivariate function at a point (x,y) in Python using Sympy

Tags: python, sympy, calculus

I have used Sympy for a project and was able to successfully generate the nth derivative for a given function and store all n derivatives in a list.

The goal is to evaluate all these derivatives at x = 0 and y = 0 and store in a separate list.

Is there a way to evaluate functions at x,y=0,0 using Sympy? Below is the code so far:

```py
def compute_nth_derivative(func):
    
    p_d_x = []
    p_d_y = []
    
    p_d_x.append(sy.diff(func,x)) # 1st derivative w.r.t x
    p_d_y.append(sy.diff(func,y)) # 1st derivative w.r.t y
    
    for i in range(n-1):
        p_d_x.append(sy.diff(p_d_x[i],x)) # nth derivative w.r.t x
        p_d_y.append(sy.diff(p_d_y[i],y)) # nth derivative w.r.t y
```

**Edit:** the answer from @Chris du Plessis in the comments solved the question.

Comment: How about `p_d_x.append(sy.diff(p_d_x[i], x).subs({x: 0, y: 0}))`? Also, please use [syntax highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) instead of pasting in a screenshot.

Comment: @Maelstrom I tried it and it worked. thanks a lot